# Unable to start multiple Processes (C#)

Tags: c#, process, console

I am unable to successfully start multiple processes from a console application.
I have a visual studio solution with a console application A, which must start multiple instances of another console application (B).

B runs in a loop catching incoming network traffic on a port specified in the process arguments.

To simplify the problem, I have removed any network logic and made it as basic as possible, yet I still have the same problem.

Code for A, where Test.exe is console application B:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {

               System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "Test.exe" });                  

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Code for B:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (Console.KeyAvailable == false || Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + counter);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            counter++;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Once I run console application A in Visual Studio debug, A pops up as intended, but only one window of B pops up starting to count as specified. However, if I look in my task manager I can see that in fact two Test.exe is running, where one is using 116K memory and the other is using 180,000K memory.

Once the counter reaches 15, it closes and opens two new windows which both starts counting from 0. This behavior continues, opening new instances of B every time counter reaches 15 until 5 instances is running as specified in A.

Obviously this behaviour is not what I intended, I want A to launch B 5 times (in this example) immediately without waiting for the proccesses to exit.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour when you run A outside of VS?

Comment: I just tested, and I get 5 Test.exe instances immediately.

Comment: If I run A outside of VS, the behaviour is erratic, sometimes launching 5, sometimes launching 4. However, after 10 seconds, they all close down and a new single instance of B pops up and again I can see two proccess of Test.exe in task manager with one using 116K memory and the other using 180,000K memory.

Comment: Even if I remove the loop in A and only start a single process, my task manager says two instances of B is running with the aforementioned memory usage.

Comment: Program A is not supposed to wait for anything but continue executing after launching B

Answer (score 0):

After re-installing .net and removing certain features I no longer needed, it is finally working as intended. Starting 50 instances is no problem and the weird memory usage is no longer evident.

The culprit was either Windows Phone SDK or Windows Azure for VS.